# Как сложить каждую строчку матрицы и вектор?

Tags: python

Не могу сложить каждую строку матрицы с вектором. Не понимаю, что делаю не так. Сначала считываю их с таблицы Excel, потом хочу сложить и снова записать.

Выводит ошибку

> list index out of range

Я знаю, что это за ошибка, но не понимаю , как исправить, так как уже по-разному пробовала.

```
import openpyxl as opx
import cv2
import win32com
import win32com.client
import numpy as np
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Fill
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side

def logic():
delta_aoa2 = []
delta_aoa2_1 = []
aoa_limit_m_018 = []
aoa_limit_m_018_1=[]
def excel_read2():
    Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'C:\\Users\\source\\DATA_MACH_0.18.xlsx')
    sh4 = wb.Worksheets('Лист4')
    sh2 = wb.Worksheets('Лист2')
    # sh = wb.ActiveSheet(3)
    # val1 = sh3.Cells(2,2).value
    for i in range(5):
        delta_aoa2.append([])
        for j in range(4):
            val4 = sh4.Cells(i+3,j+2).value
            delta_aoa2[i].append(val4)
            delta_aoa2_1=np.matrix(delta_aoa2)
    print(delta_aoa2_1)
    for i in range(4):
        val6 = sh2.Cells(i+3,2).value
        aoa_limit_m_018.append(val6)
        aoa_limit_m_018_1=np.matrix(aoa_limit_m_018)
    print(aoa_limit_m_018_1)
    wb.Save()

    wb.Close()
    Excel.Quit()
excel_read2()

#Сложение строк матрицы с вектором
aoa_limit_calc1 = []
def aoa_limit_calc_1():
    for i in range(5):
        aoa_limit_calc1.append([])
        for j in range(4):
            val7 = delta_aoa2_1[i][j]+aoa_limit_m_018_1[j]
            aoa_limit_calc1[i].append(val7)
print(aoa_limit_calc1)            
aoa_limit_calc_1()
#запись в таблицу
def excel_entry():
    wb = opx.load_workbook('source/DATA_MACH_0.18.xlsx',data_only = True)
    sh = wb['Лист5']
    for j in range(11):
        sh.cell(row = 4 , column = j+2).value = delta_aoa_sp[j]
       
    wb.save("result/DATA_MACH_0.18.xlsx")

excel_entry()
```

`delta_aoa2` здесь:

```
    [[ 0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
     [-2.05 -2.    0.    0.  ]
     [-3.05 -3.   -1.   -1.  ]
     [-3.55 -3.5  -1.5  -2.  ]
     [-4.55 -4.4  -2.   -2.5 ]]
```

`aoa_limit_m_018`:

```
    [[ 0.  5. 24. 28.]]
```

Xочу получить матрицу `aoa_limit_calc1`:

```
    [[ 0.   5.   24.   28.  ]
     [-2.05 3.   24.   28.  ]
     [-3.05 2.   23.   27.  ]
     [-3.55 1.5  22.5  26.  ]
     [-4.55 0.6  22.   25.5 ]]
```

Comment: По-моему, я этот вопрос уже видел. Вы можете оставить в вопросе только ту часть, которая его касается? чтобы не читать всю простыню.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе пример матрицы, вектора и результата, который вы хотите получить. А вообще чтобы сложить матрицу и вектор в Numpy: `res = matrix + vector` ;)

Comment: @MaxU Добавила результат, остальное было после кода) так пробовала почему-то не работало, может неправильно сам цикл прописала...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вам, возможно, просто нужен `numpy.add()`:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
arr2 = np.random.randint(100, 200, 4)
# arr1:
# [[ 0  1  2  3]
#  [ 4  5  6  7]
#  [ 8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15]]
# arr2:
# [198 112 122 195]
```

```
res = np.add(arr1, arr2)
# res:
# [[198 113 124 198]
#  [202 117 128 202]
#  [206 121 132 206]
#  [210 125 136 210]]
```

Comment: не ругается, но выводит []

Comment: приведите свой код, где с моим решением у вас "не ругается, но выводит []"

Comment: def aoa_limit_calc_1(): aoa_limit_calc=np.add(delta_aoa2,aoa_limit_m_018_1) print(aoa_limit_calc)    
    aoa_limit_calc_1()

Comment: в  общем если прописать aoa_limit_calc=np.add(delta_aoa2,aoa_limit_m_018_1) внутри функции excel_read2(), то работает, но почему в отдельной функции aoa_limit_calc_1() у меня это же не работает объясните пожалуйста?(((

Comment: @Miss.A седя по симптомам, у вам проблемы с областью видимости переменных. то есть, в отдельную функцию не передаются данные для обработки.

Comment: похоже, но очень странно, ибо у меня есть еще одна другая функция, в которой все работает, но там у меня, правда , нет матрицы.

Comment: Вам нужно научиться правильно работать с функциональным программированием. не нужно надеяться, что вдруг ваши данные будут видны в текущей области видимости. лучше их передавать в явном виде в функцию как параметр (в скобочках).

Comment: поняла, большое вам спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

Исходные данные:

```
In [68]: m
Out[68]:
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [-2.05, -2.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [-3.05, -3.  , -1.  , -1.  ],
       [-3.55, -3.5 , -1.5 , -2.  ],
       [-4.55, -4.4 , -2.  , -2.5 ]])

In [69]: v
Out[69]:
array([[ 0.],
       [ 5.],
       [24.],
       [28.]])
```

решение:

```
In [70]: res = m + v.ravel()
```

результат:

```
In [71]: res
Out[71]:
array([[ 0.  ,  5.  , 24.  , 28.  ],
       [-2.05,  3.  , 24.  , 28.  ],
       [-3.05,  2.  , 23.  , 27.  ],
       [-3.55,  1.5 , 22.5 , 26.  ],
       [-4.55,  0.6 , 22.  , 25.5 ]])
```